# GET request working in postman but not with Postman

Tags: jquery, get, request, fetch, postman

I'm currently working on a project for a company. This company is asking me to make a GET request on their API. So they gave me a screenshot of a POSTMAN request :

[image: Postman Screenshot]

But I can't do a fetch request with some body data like postman do, and the API does not take POST request.

[image: Fetch request screenshot]

How can I make the request work? I've tried everything with the parameters. Each time I try, the console shows an Internal Server error 500, saying to me the server can't do a toLowerCase() on undefined, so I guess the API can't understand the data I'm sending.

I also tried to remove double quotes to data, add some, even to the guest number, nothing changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see from our screenshot, firstly 'GET' calls do not have a body. So please try to remove it first and look for how to pass data in 'GET' calls. If you are passing any data in POST call then first stringify your data which you are going to send in your body too.

To understand how to make calls in right way you can also take help from this link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Okay thanks, but I don't understand why in postman we can put a Body in a GET request.